# Which Design pattern should i use to maintain pre initialized set of objects?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have some pre initialized objects of some class. These objects are heavy weight objects and each correspond to some configuration options specified by user. There will be exactly one instance corresponding to one configuration and same will be used every time.

My question is, which design pattern suits best to handle this kind of situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely a Flyweight is what you are looking for. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern
This can be used for pre-initialise heavy weight objects and reuse them.

Comment: What ever example i see on web it has used data structure like Map in order to store the objects. I hope it is not mandatory because I have created a Manager class which manages the objects and based on some criteria returns the appropriate object.

Comment: @BalkrishanNagpal a map is just simple way of doing that, and not mandatory.